# How to open Gmail Login Activity by using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

I want to open **Gmail Login Activities** directly from another app using **Intent**. I am able to open **gmail app** by using its **package** name **com.google.android.gm**. But I am wondering how to open its Login Activities directly as activities are show below

[image] [image]

1. What are the URI's of these activities?
   OR
2. How can I get these URI's?

Comment: how many gmail account is there in your app?? Are you able to switch your account in this activity?

Comment: There are 4 accounts and i can switch my account in this activity.

Comment: See if this helps you https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: @AdeelIftikhar these activities are not the part of Gmail it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots you provided here is not the part of Gmail Activities, instead these are the part of Android OS it self and known as `AccountManager`.

check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager) to learn more about it

**Now the Main Answer:-**

As you specified that you want to launch these through your intent, you can do

```
//pass the action while creating intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);

//setting type for Google Accounts
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[] {"com.google"});

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Just one extra thing, few custom Android OS like linage OS, does not include this account manager by default.

Comment: What is the URI of these activities like as Gmail application has com.google.android.gm URI and we can open gmail from another app using this URI in that application.

Comment: @AdeelIftikhar i tried searching on documentation, but it seems google not mentioned this info, i can suggest to you look into source code of Android OS ,but i'm also not sure if it's here https://source.android.com/

Comment: Is it possible to access these activities through accessibility service?